# Is the OPA860 a diamond transistor?

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, transconductance

I was looking at using the OPA860 for a voltage controlled load. Reading in the [OPA860 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/product/opa860) it says:

> The OPA860 combines a high-performance buffer with a transconductance
>   section. This transconductance section is discussed in the OTA The
>   buffer section of the OPA860 is an 1600MHz, (Operational
>   Transconductance Amplifier) section of 4000V/μs closed-loop buffer
>   that can be used as a this data sheet. Over the years and depending on
>   the building block for AGC amplifiers, LED driver circuit, writer, the
>   OTA section of an op amp has been integrator for fast pulse, fast
>   control loop amplifiers, referred to as a Diamond Transistor, and
>   control amplifiers for capacitive sensors and Voltage-Controlled
>   Current source, Transconductor, active filters.

Are they achieving the transconductance with regular boring silicon tech (which is probably the case) or something else?

My main reason for asking the question is because its a cool part (low noise and transconductance), and because even though I suspect there is no secret sauce maybe there is, it also says ±1.2V differential input which I thought was interesting.

[image]

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa071/sboa071.pdf

Comment: I glossed over that because the other part looked better, Thanks

Comment: It is traditionally referred to as a diamond buffer. Extremely high speed current amplifier.

Comment: Actually, to answer my own question it is "a diamond transistor", but a diamond transistor is a configuration of transistors, not a transistor made of diamonds. "The monolithic integrated circuit OPA660 uses the Dia- mond structure to act as an ideal transistor"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a particular [complementary BJT circuit arrangement](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa071/sboa071.pdf) as so:

[image]

Which behaves similarly to transistor that does not have a Vbe offset and biasing issues, as explained in the link which @user3528438 also provided in a comment.

It's made with Burr-Brown/TI's high performance silicon analog IC process, not carbon-based.

Comment: It also doesn't have polarity; it takes negative "base" voltage to give  negative "collector" current.

Comment: Looks like a section of a nice pin-driver to me, except for the low output compliance voltage. Pricey!

Answer (score 2):

[This document from TI says it is a particular configuration rather than exotic materials](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa071/sboa071.pdf)

I also found other references to the diamond structure that also refer to it being a particular circuit configuration.

But, transistors made of diamond appear to be real thing, also.  Only found references to research, though.  No commercial products that I could find (though they might exist, I just didn't make a thorough search.